# Removing data from a df with conditions in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove rows in a Dataframe based off a distinct Value in one column and the count of non nan data in a second column where that count is equal to zero.

Here is the original df:

```
   ColA ColB
0     a    1
1     a    2
2     a  NaN
3     a  NaN
4     b  NaN
5     b  NaN
6     b  NaN
7     b  NaN
8     c    4
9     c    5
10    c    6
11    c  NaN
```

I want the new df to have index 4-7 removed because the distinct value of 'b' in ColA has a count on non nan values in ColB=0

```
  ColA ColB
0    a    1
1    a    2
2    a  NaN
3    a  NaN
4    c    4
5    c    5
6    c    6
7    c  NaN
```

I can think of a few ways to do this with creating an array of the distinct values the iterating through the df and array to get what I need but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

via `groupby()`+`transform()` so check if column 'ColB' is not `NaN` Since it give you boolean Series of True/False then you can groupby df['ColA'] and transform the first occurance of True/False for the whole group then after filtering drop the index by using `reset_index()`

```
df[df['ColB'].notna().groupby(df['ColA']).transform('first')].reset_index(drop=True)
#you can also use .loc[]
```

output:

```
    ColA    ColB
0   a       1.0
1   a       2.0
2   a       NaN
3   a       NaN
4   c       4.0
5   c       5.0
6   c       6.0
7   c       NaN
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I really like the groupby()+transform() but I don't really understand it. Can you explain that one on how it works?

Comment: @dasrocko sure pls wait let me add explainations

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) with `any` to select groups which contain "any" valid value, and then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df[
    df['ColB'].notna().groupby(df['ColA']).transform('any')
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or the DeMorgan's equivalent with not all `NaN`:

```
df = df[
    ~df['ColB'].isna().groupby(df['ColA']).transform('all')
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df`:

```
  ColA  ColB
0    a   1.0
1    a   2.0
2    a   NaN
3    a   NaN
4    c   4.0
5    c   5.0
6    c   6.0
7    c   NaN
```